# Is Freedom in existentialism compatible with determinism

Tags: existentialism, determinism

Is freedom in existentialism compatible with determinism.    Or does it simply refer to the subjective experience of deciding amongst a variety of possibilities

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that the subjective experience is no more than just that.   There is no true freedom as the previous occurring events have determined a definite outcome irrelevant to the subjective experience of freedom

Comment: There are many philosophies that have been labeled existentialist. Which philosophers' views are you referring to when you say existentialism?  This helps provide a context for the question which limits it in some way so a brief answer that is reasonably objective can be provided in some way. Welcome!

Comment: What do you mean "true freedom?" What would it look like if it existed? How would it be different from what I seem to be walking around in?

Comment: Yes, according to Sartre and his source, Nietzsche. Possible duplicate of [Existentialism and the absensce of free will](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/existentialism-and-the-absensce-of-free-will)

Comment: ?Nietzsche, a source for Sartre?

Comment: Sartre does not assert that there is no determinism "out there" in the universe. The universe and its causalities are given to us as _facticity and its contingencies_. But he claims that consciousness defines itself as what is _not_ facticity or Being (separates from it by _nothingness or rejection_). This is what his frredom is about. Consciousness is obliged to determine itself because it cannor be determined by the universe, being split off from it.